# using python function in c++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11

I want to use python string functions to parse c++ std::string object. I checked the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#back-to-the-example , but couldn't find (or understand) all the required details.

For example python function `f1` strip and split string using comma,

```
def f1(str):
    return str.split(str.strip(),',')
```

Then, how do I call this function in C++ code?

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
int main()  {
    std::string str1 = "  A , B , C , D  ";
   // how to pass str1 to python f1() ?
}
```

Comment: The link you linked to in your question pertains to calling `C` or `C++` modules from Python. Not the other way around.

Comment: I think you want to look at [this page of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) instead.